# zip object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, object, python-zip

Hi i am trying to cluster my data by using fuzzy clustering. I came across the codes from https://github.com/ShristiK/Fuzzy-C-Means-Clustering/blob/master/fuzzy%20c-means%20.ipynb by shristi but i am getting the zip object error, when trying to display results. I tried converting the zip object to a listby using list(zip(*membership_mat)) in Step2 but then i get list object is not an iterator. Any help to resolve this so i can display results will be appreciated.
Thanks

I tried converting the zip object to a listby using list(zip(*membership_mat)) in Step2 but then i get list object is not an iterator. Any help to resolve this so i can display results will be appreciated.
I am hoping to resolve this issue so i can display the results and see my clusters as well as the accuracy metrics.